# Object not found! in Codeigniter Login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter and I'm trying to build a login form by following some tutorials. However, when I try to submit the login form in order to validate the credentials that have been inputted by calling the validate_login function in the login controller , I get the "Object not Found" Error. Every time I click my submit button, my URL redirects to "http://localhost/pgevCI/login/validate_login", but it still gets the Object not Found error.

Controller: login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'view_login';
        $this->load->view('includes/login_template', $data);    
    }
function validate_login()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_accounts');
        $valid = $this->model_accounts->validate();

        if($valid)
        {
            $data = array(
                'userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data); 
            redirect('site/admin');
        }

        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }       
      }
    }
```

View form: view_login.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/validate_login" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="user-name" aria-label="..." placeholder="Enter your username">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="user-password" aria-label="..." placeholder="Enter your password">
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

    </br>
    </br>
    <!-- Standard button -->
    <div class="action-buttons text-center">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Sign In</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom">Forgot your password?</button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Model: model_accounts.php

```
class Model_accounts extends CI_Model {

    function validate() 
    {

        $this->db->where('userid', $this->input->post('userid'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {

            return true;    
        }
    }
}
```

Base URL & Index File :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pgevCI/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGADG.png)

Any help would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: In my experience, I used ```$config['index_page'] = '';``` and ```$config['base_url'] = '';```; both blank. I never used anything yet. And everytime I have ```.htaccess``` file to remove ```index.php``` from url. Try it once.

Comment: Here's my .htaccess file, please check if it still needs changes: 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pgevCI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Can you refer this repository for the code of config and htaccess? https://github.com/kishor10d/Admin-Panel-User-Management-using-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
<?php echo site_url('login/validate_login') ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/validate_login
```

You haven't set CI to use nice URLs, so your real redirect url is

```
http://localhost/pgevCI/index.php/login/validate_login
```

You have to set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and use a htaccess if you want the urls to appear like

```
http://localhost/pgevCI/login/validate_login
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add following...

```
function __construct()
{
$this->load->helper('url');
}
```

You have to load helper `url` so that you can use `base_url()`.

If not work comment i can help more in codeigniter.Thank you.

If you are using `autoload.php` for loading then make this `TRUE` in `congig.php`.

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Oh your mistake is here.... You want to load view `view_login` but in your code what view is loading see carefully.So

Replace

```
 function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'view_login';
        $this->load->view('includes/login_template', $data);    
    }
```

By

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('includes/login_template/view_login');    
}
```

Also

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/login/validate_login');" method="POST">
```

For Model , first save file as `Model_accounts.php`with following code.

```
class Model_accounts extends CI_Model {

    function validate() 
    {

        $this->db->where('userid', $this->input->post('userid'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();

        if(count($query)==1)
        {

            return true;    
        }
    }
}
```

OR just replace it

```
if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {

            return true;    
        }
```

By

```
 if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {

            return true;    
        }
```

Hope it will work if code is correct in your model.

Comment: Hello! I have already added the helper in my autoload.php, but it still doesn't work : 
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');

Thank you!

Comment: Did you make `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;' in `config.php`.

Comment: once try using constructor.as above if not comment.

Comment: I was able to load the view properly, however, there seems to be a problem with how the function "validate_login" is being called in the login controller when I try to submit the form for sign in

Comment: did save your file as `Login.php`.And if possible also share your model code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to mention 'index.php' in your every url. to avoid repeat. just modify your config base url following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pgevCI/';

change this to

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/pgevCI/index.php';
```